# Private Ethereum blockchain with Web3

Tags: go-ethereum, web3.py

Using instructions from [here](https://medium.com/@rangersz2018/setting-a-multi-node-private-ethereum-blockchain-with-proof-of-authority-a804fec4b1c3) I have a local private Ethereum blockchain running in a distributed envoirnment as per the diagram below:

`|---------|   Blockchain Node (192.168.122.111) |---------|`

`|---------|   Processor Node (192.168.122.222) |---------|`

**Blockchain Node** -  `geth` terminal is running here.

**Processor Node** - does some calculations and write to the Blockchain Node where `geth` terminal is running. A `web3.py` script is running here which sends contract deployment request to the blockchain node.

These two nodes are in the same network, and can `ping` each other. Also I have tried file transfer with Python and its working perfectly.

My problem is: When I try to connected from the `Processor Node` to the `Blockchain Node` through this code unable to connect. Please help where I am making mistake?

`w3 = Web3(http://192.168.122.111:30000)`

`account = Account()`

`acct = account.privateKeyToAccount(private_key_of_Processing_Node) // also tried with private key of Blockchain node`
**EDIT**

**Error:** `Could not discover provider while making request: method:eth_chainId`

Also I am using following command to connect to `geth` on the **blockchain node**

`geth --port 3000 --networkid 58343 --datadir=./eth-blockchain --maxpeers=5 --rpc --rpcport 8543 --rpcaddr 192.168.122.111 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal,miner" console 2>>eth.log`

Comment: You have to connect to the RPC port, from the processor node `w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://192.168.122.111:8543"))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
w3 = Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://192.168.122.111:<rpc port>'))
w3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey)
```

"rpc port" you set in geth command lines params( --rpcport ) in blockchain node.

Comment: This command is giving me `syntax error`. Changed to `w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://192.168.122.111:3000'))`, but same error. I think am making some error in the `geth` call. Please check my edits